# How to show a user profile by passing username just after the domain name

Tags: codeigniter-url

I am creating a site with Codeigniter. I have to show the customers profile page when a customer type his username after the domain, like **" www.mydomain.com/username ".** please give me an advice. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will hold this information in PHP. Your htaccess redirect should look something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Then in index.php $_GET['i'] will hold the value of whatever is in the URL after the domain