# How to show user profile by entering url like example.com/username in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, profile

I want to create asp.net mvc3 application in which when user enter into website like 
`example.com` he will be shown login page or when he enter username in url like `example.com/username` then he will be able to see his or other users's profile. Please suggest me some tutorial.

Similar question but i want in asp.net mvc3
[How to show a user profile by passing username just after the domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936748/how-to-show-a-user-profile-by-passing-username-just-after-the-domain-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558541/what-kind-of-route-would-i-need-to-provide-vanity-urls/13641225), 
see if it helps you. In your case the action to show user profile needs be served for anonymous users also.

hope this helps.

Comment: can you provide me a linkto any good tutorial regarding this issue...where i have to add first part of the code  `public class VanityUrlContraint : IRouteConstraint
`

Comment: you can check http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426125/Creating-custom-route-constraints-in-ASP-NET-MVC for insight in custom route constraint.